# Change selected Treeview Node on Datagridview Cell Click

Tags: c#, datagridview, treeview

I need some assistance with the following code, I am trying to get the code to check if a node exists in the treeview then select it.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null)
        {
            string CellSelected = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();

            if (treeView1.Nodes.ContainsKey(CellSelected))
            {
                this.treeView1.SelectedNode.Name = CellSelected;
                this.treeView1.Select();
            }
        }

    }
```

once the treeview node is selected it needs to fire the following code

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = null;
        dataGridView1.Visible = false;

        if(treeView1.SelectedNode.Name=="test")
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = _1.Properties.Resources._7E7907_2;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used treeviews particularly much, but have you considered you might have to do a recursive search through all nodes, and child nodes, and child of child nodes, and so forth? As far as I can tell, you're only looping through the first layer of treeview nodes.